# How do I check if a string is in a certain format

Tags: c, string, scanf

In a project I'm working on, I'm importing settings from a `.txt` file.
To make this work, I need to validate that the first row of a text file is written in a certain format. The format should be `%d,%d`. 2 integers with a comma in between them, for example `7,7` or `150,20`. I've tried using `sscanf` and `strcmp` in the following ways to make it work, but with no luck.

```
fgets(line, 100, fp);
int s1, s2;

if (!(sscanf(line, "%d,%d", s1, s2))) {
    return 1;
}
if (!(strcmp(line, "%d,%d"))) {
    return 1;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: pcre can do the job

Comment: Read up on `strspn()`. ASCII digit(s) - comma - ASCII digit(s) - null terminator. (Read up on what the scanf() family of functions return, too... You've made assumptions that are wrong.)

Comment: `if( !(sscanf(line,"%d,%d", s1, s2)) )` should be `if(sscanf(line,"%d ,%d", &s1, &s2) != 2)` note several details of the changes. The most important being the `&` address-of operator.

Comment: Mystified as why you try to compare the input line, which is supposed to be say `150,20` with some format specs string. `strcmp` does not understand them. Those `"%d"` etc. format specs only apply to functions like `scanf` and `printf` where they have some similar, but actually quite different rules.

Comment: @Psi for this I think it's probably overkill. If you wanted that to be the only thing on the line, maybe `if(sscanf(line, " %d,%d %c", &s1, &s2, &syntax_error) != 2)`. Don't forget to validate the line endings.

Comment: @Neil granted. But it _can_ do the job. Depends on whether you want to go for a comfortable or a lean solution. At least for me, pcre is in fact quite comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf), `sscanf()` returns the number of variables successfully written to or `-1` on error. If the return value is less than 2, one or more of the variables could not be read.

Another problem is you should pass pointers to `s1` and `s2`, not the variables themselves.

Try the following:

```
fgets(line, 100, fp);
int s1, s2;
if (sscanf(line,"%d,%d", &s1, &s2) < 2) {
    return 1;
}
```

`strcmp()` cannot be used here as it does not handle placeholders. It will test if the string is equal to the literal string `"%d,%d"`.